# Possible to implement more code, so that highligted dates does'nt show until "in progress" is written

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, calendar

I am coordinating a large amount of production orders that are linked to thereown projects.
In the worksheet that I am working on I have created a calendar which
I have managed to highlight weekend days and holidays using conditional formatting.
I also managed from this website to implement a code so that the days/dates from start to end date where highlighted also.
I manage to do this by using this formula =AND(Q$6>=$I7,Q$6<=$J7)
Now I wonder if it is possible to implement something in this code so that the colour does
not show until I write in progress in the text cell. (Pågående = In progress, Ikke startet = Not started, Venter på = Waiting on) I want the gray colour to show only when i write In progress = pågående, and not show when i write Ikke startet = not started. i want the colour to be shown even if i write Waiting on. I'm using microsoft office 365 (office 16) See picture.
[image: How it looks today]

Comment: Add the desired value to the condition? It would be useful to see the columns & rows as part of your screen cap so we could know what cells the formula you mention refers to.

Comment: as above seems like you just need to add one more condition in your `AND` formula to check the "in progress" flag.

Comment: I edited the question and implemented the exact formula used in the conditional formatting. You can also see an updated picture with row letters and numbers. Any suggestions on what condition and how to write it so that the in progress is checked?

Comment: Does anybody know what kind of condition and how to implement it to the formula?